# Install Mongoid with Rails 3.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

i'm trying to use Mongoid with rails 3.2.2, i've added:

```
gem "mongoid", "~> 2.4"
gem "bson_ext", "~> 1.5"
```

to my gemfile, run:

```
bundle install
```

then

```
rails g mongoid:config
```

then edited my application.rb so:

```
#require "active_record/railtie" commented because of mongoid
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

and i have mongoid.yml:

```
development:
  host: localhost
  database: boards_development

test:
  host: localhost
  database: boards_test

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
  # slaves:
  #   - host: slave1.local
  #     port: 27018
  #   - host: slave2.local
  #     port: 27019
```

I've deleted databse.yml as is said on mongoid docs but when running rails server I get error like this:

```
matteo@matteo-stable:~/Matteo/Dev/boards$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x8eb762c> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/matteo/Matteo/Dev/boards/config/environments/development.rb:26:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
    from /home/matteo/Matteo/Dev/boards/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/matteo/Matteo/Dev/boards/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/matteo/Matteo/Dev/boards/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /home/matteo/Matteo/Dev/boards/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/matteo/Matteo/Dev/boards/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/matteo/Matteo/Dev/boards/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
matteo@matteo-stable:~/Matteo/Dev/boards$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
host is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
[2012-03-16 20:00:08] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-03-16 20:00:08] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-02-16) [i686-linux]
[2012-03-16 20:00:08] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=9936 port=3000
^C[2012-03-16 20:01:03] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2012-03-16 20:01:03] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
Exiting
```

leaving the line about active record i don't get any error but this:

```
host is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
```

should i install something other?

Comment: oh no it's only stackoverflow

Comment: I had a similar problem (except the host issue)--but you're NOT supposed to delete database.yml, according to their docs:

"Now that you have a mongoid.yml you can't wait to delete that pesky database.yml, right? Do it and you'll start getting ActiveRecord errors all over the place." http://mongoid.org/docs/installation/configuration.html  @pierre-louis-g has the right fix, below. I commented out both lines mentioning active-record and my install works now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You removed ActiveRecord from your app, but you still have its config options. Look in environment.rb and application.rb (and other files under /config) for "active_record".

Answer (score 5):

Try to to use rails templates next time. They will help you to start faster and will add a lot of other nice gems you will need very soon:

https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates

If you want to setup a rails3 project without active record, use this command and add mongoid to Gemfile later without any hassle:

```
rails new appname --skip-active-record
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to also comment to lines of code in config/environments/development.rb

Since Rails 3.2 they adding 2 lines of code which calls "active_record" in this file. Just comment it

```
  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

EDIT: About the host problem, it's weird but the answer is no you should not have to install something else...